# Terminal accidentally runs commands while trying to make Git commit

Tags: python, git, shell, ubuntu

We're trying to write a script that will publish articles based on commit history. We ran the following command and instead of making a commit, it actually dropped us into a Python terminal:

````
cchilders:~/blogplish (master) 
$ git commit -m "You can run this file using the `python` command in your terminal:\n```$ python blogplish.py\nThe script is working.```"
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jul  1 2016, 15:12:24) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
````

We're curious as to why it did this, which of the two Pythons in the above command caused the issue. Also, how we can prevent this when we make commits like this. The target language that our script will generate is markdown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Python itself, nor Git, and everything to do with your shell (command line interpreter).

Most Unix-ish shells share some syntactic features:

- Single quotes are "strong quotes", protecting against almost all or all expansions, and are ended only by another single quote.
- Double quotes are "weak quotes", protecting against *some* expansions, but specifically allowing variable value replacements like `$var` and backquote expansions like `` `command` ``.  Note, however, that double quotes quote single quotes, so `"he said 'hello'"` retains the inner single quotes.

In this case, the:

```
"... `python` ..."
```

part told your shell to run `python` and see what it produced on its standard output.  Whatever that was would be substituted in place at that point.

(This kind of backquote expansion is tricky to use.  If you *want* it, it's usually better to use `$(...)` instead, since the parentheses help humans figure out what is inside the command, and nesting becomes obvious: `reprocess $(process --files $(ls))` means:

- run `ls`
- using its output as arguments, run `process --files`
- using its output as arguments, run `reprocess`

If `ls` prints `README hello.txt`, this is like running `process --files README hello.txt`.  Whatever `process` prints is then spliced into the arguments to `reprocess`.)

To complete the items here, first *all* backquoted expressions are going to get run and spliced, in sequence.  There are four pairs of backquotes:

```
`python`
``
`$ python blogplish.py\nThe script is working.`
``
```

Two of these are empty, so they run nothing and splice nothing.  One runs `python`, and the last runs `$`, which will likely produce:

```
$: not found
```

But before the shell gets to that point it must first finish the first `python` (and then run the empty command).

Last, as others mentioned, you can just run without `-m`, or use the stronger quote variants with `-m`.  There is one more alternative, for which we need [the `git commit` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html): commits can be run with `-F <file>` or `--file=<file>` to read the message from a prepared file.  You can even use `-F -` to read the message from standard input:

```
printf '%s\n\n%s\n' 'commit subject' 'commit message body' | git commit -F -
```

for instance.

Comment: "It's usually better to use..." Assuming that one is intentionally using expansion.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: er, yes. :-)

Comment: This is by far the best answer since it explains why the OP is seeing the behavior in question. The only small draw back is that you do not explicitly prescribe a solution.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest that you leave off the `-m` flag and use the text editor (vim by default) to edit your message. This will avoid the command-line interpreting your message as a command. If you are unfamiliar with vim, you can set the text editor to something more to your liking.

p.s. Another benefit of editing your message in a text editor is that you can enter a multiline message much more easily. This is particularly beneficial when you have team conventions governing your commit messages. Also, services like GitHub don't behave well with long, single-line commit messages.

Comment: You're all right, and we probably will use nano for this in general. I picked the top one because it gave the most detail. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Code-Apprentice gives a great option.

If you really want to provide a commit message on the command line you should be able to use single quotes instead of double quotes:

````
git commit -m 'You can run this file using the `python` command in your terminal:\n```$ python blogplish.py\nThe script is working.```'
````

Bash (the default shell on Ubuntu systems) [doesn't process backticks in single-quoted strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html#Single-Quotes).